# Readable/clearer type on 3D rotated images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, typesetting, mockup, font-design

I'm using a lot of 3D rotated images, especially in mockups. I've always noticed that text become slightly less clear when they're rotated. I've always accepted this, since I thought there was no way to render text in such way that the type remains perfectly clear.

However, a friend of mine attended me that this problem can be undone! Too bad he couldn't remember how to.

Because so, I'd like to ask you guys: How you get clearer type when images/type layers are 3D rotated, especially in mockups?

Thanks!

Example:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting an example?

Comment: Kinda stupid, asking such question, but can't really come up with great examples. However, I've opened a few that quickly came to mind and made a lossless screenshot of these three images. In reality, on websites and such, the images appear smaller than they're shown in the screenshot. At this size, type becomes quite readable, but I imagine it can be -much!- clearer. Same goes when images are shown small.

http://nl.tinypic.com/r/imtcfp/8

Comment: What are your methods for putting these in perspective?  How big are the images you are starting with versus the expected output?

Comment: I pretty must (99%) always use PSD mockups with smart layers I can insert my PSD layers into. Often downloaded from Freebiesbug.com, but I wouldn't mind any where. I don't work with mockups that are smaller than the desired output. Besides that, most mockups are at least 1920x1080.

True is that the desired output in dimensions is always smaller than the starting point. Often starting with 1440p/2160p PSD files, while the output is somewhere near 1080P or even 1000x1000. Is this enough information?